# onTouch listener, toggleButton in wrong state

Tags: android

I have a toggleButton hooked up to an onTouch listener, when I press the button the image changes and the so does the text. When I let go the image should change back and so should the text. it all works fine apart from when I let go of the button, the text only changes back for a fraction of a second, then returns to the "on" text. The image works fine, why is this?

xml:

```
 <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/PTT_button5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="@string/ptt5"
        android:textOn="Push To Talk On"
        android:textOff="Push To Talk Off"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_lightblue_glossy"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
```

java:

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(!serviceConnected) {
            return true;
        }
        int action = event.getAction();
        try {
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                service.sendDtmf(callId, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STAR);
                service.sendDtmf(callId, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9);
                ((ToggleButton) v).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                ((ToggleButton) v).setChecked(true);
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                service.sendDtmf(callId, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POUND);
                service.sendDtmf(callId, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POUND);
                ((ToggleButton) v).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                ((ToggleButton) v).setChecked(false);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(THIS_FILE, "Cannot ask sip service to send dtmf", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToggleBUtton` has its own listener to change it state. Since you are returning false, what happens is:

1) `onTouch` happens, and so the button state is changed `ON-->OFF`

2) `listener` of the toogle button is then called (since you returned false, event is not consumed), so state changes `OFF --> ON`

Just remove the following lines, now the text will change when you release the toggle button.

```
((ToggleButton) v).setChecked(true);
```

and

```
((ToggleButton) v).setChecked(false);
```

**Update** since you require the text to change while the button is being touched (not after touch released).

```
return true
```

from the touch listener, wont call the listener of the toggle button.

Alternatively, as you mentioned, just use a normal button :)

Comment: Hi, this method doesn't work because of the onTouch functionality, that method only changes the text after you let go of a toggleButton. What will happen is the text will stay the same when I press the button, will change once I let go from one state to another, essentially I am overwriting this listener with my own, which i have done many times before, yet this time it has a bug.

Comment: I suppose I can just change to a Button and use setText instead of messing around.

Comment: Wait, you want the `text` to change while pressing it? Then simply return `true` from the touch listener..

Comment: Ah yes, that will stop it changing state twice great.